# Determine if an asp:Placeholder is visible Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a program with two`asp:Placeholder`s with `runat = "server"`. Only one will be visible at a time. I want to determine which on is through javasacript and jquery. I have tried a few commands but none have worked. So far I have tried (these are all in an `if` statement:

```
if ($'#showClosest').visible)
if ($'#showClosest').style.visibility)
if ($'#showClosest').css.visible)
if ($'#showClosest').css.visibility)
```

None of them have worked/returned true, even when the place holder is visible.

Is there a way to determine if the `placeholder` is `visible`?

I need to do this through placeholders to. The info I get from the pageload will determine what is visible and what is not.

**EDIT:**

Here are the placeholders:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID = "showClosest" runat = "server">
<asp:PlaceHolder ID = "showSelectedInformation" runat = "server">
```

and here is how I set the visibilities (page load):

```
if (Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains(src.Config.Title))
{
     //Code

     //Make correct divs visible
     showSelectedInformation.Visible = true;
     showClosest.Visible = false;

 }else{
     //Make sure correct divs are visible
     showSelectedInformation.Visible = false;
     showClosest.Visible = true;
 }
```

Comment: Please show us the corresponding mark-up. Placeholders won't be rendered as such, is `#placeHolder` a specific tag you've declared on the type taking over the placeholder? Overall, insufficient data.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited it to show more code. Hopefully that should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to do it on page generation.  On your ASPX page have that Javascript:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var IsVisible = <%=PlaceHolderVisibility%>;
    </script>
</head>
```

Then in your code behind once you have processed the page, do:

```
public string PlaceHolderVisibility;

... snip ....

if(SomePlaceholder.Visible)
    PlaceHolderVisibility= "true";
else
    PlaceHolderVisibility= "false";
```

Something like that anyway.  Note that Javascript and ASP/c# process bools slightly differently in different case so be aware of that.

Then you can simply call on the IsVisible variable when you want to know if the panel is visible or not.

With pure Jquery and none of the above solution, it's going to be hard as PlaceHolder doesn't actually render anything to the DOM.  You would need an element rendered inside it that acts as a flag, but you will have to deal with instances when it isn't there/can't be found, and when it is.  Can be hard to manage.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `var IsVisible = <%=SomePlaceholder.Visible%>` and forget the whole property and wonky if/else statement (that uses strings for some reason)

Comment: @Adam, because ASP.net will render it as True I think, and Javascript will throw an error with that, it needs to read as true.  You can lowercase it and tostring it etc, but I just showed it this way for simplicity.

Comment: Bit of a harsh downvote whoever that was, if you explain why I'd appreciate it so I can make my answers better in the future.

Comment: I agree, a bit harsh (don't look at me, but maybe I caused it?).  This is true that it'll be True.  It's merely that whenever I see variables set to boolean values that are really strings, especially when it's in an `If` statement alarms go off all over the place.  Doing `SomePlaceholder.Visible.ToString().ToLower()` is well worth not having to do a property, etc.

Comment: @Adam yeah you are right I probably could of written it better, `<%=SomePlaceholder.Visible.ToString().ToLower()%> is probably better

Comment: Might be worthwhile to edit your post just for future people?

Comment: I don't know why this got a down vote. I did it and the problem was fixed

Comment: @SsRide360: I think the downvote was probably a result of what someone considered to be an excessive amount of code to return a boolean that could already be accessed declaratively.  Harsh if you ask me, but if you're doing it this way you can simply do `SomePlaceholder.Visible.ToString().ToLower()` as @Adam Terlson suggested.  If you want to use a property then have a look at [my suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665012/determine-if-an-aspplaceholder-is-visible-jquery/5666061#5666061).

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your question to  @Mr. Disappointment, yes if you add a div inside your placeholder you can check for it. It will only be in the page markup when the placeholder is visible.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="myPlaceHolder">
    <div id="foo"></div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Then in your JavaScript you just check if the element exists.

```
var placeholderVisible = ($('#foo').length > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be exceptionally simple in comparison to some given.

Go from this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID = "showClosest" runat = "server">
<asp:PlaceHolder ID = "showSelectedInformation" runat = "server">
```

to this:

```
<div id="showClosest" runat="server">
<div id="showSelectedInformation" runat="server">
```

Now the javascript and C# that you already have will work without modification, but note that referencing IDs in your javascript from controls that are set to `runat="server"` require a (.NET 4.0 only) `static` ID [rendering mode](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/hima/archive/2010/07/16/all-about-client-id-mode-in-asp-net-4.aspx).

Oh, and make sure your jQuery looks like this:

```
if ($'#showClosest').is(':visible'))
```

Comment: A possibility, but by that reasoning you could use `asp:Panel`.

Comment: I don't see your reasoning.  By yours, one could use _anything_.  .NET controls incur unnecessary overhead and I will always opt to have complete control over what markup gets rendered.  Thus, I stick with tags I can actually see and when necessary will set them to `runat='server'` to change their visibility.  If your logic is that you don't want to put the additional DIV on the page,  I think it's a valid concern, but the benefits of not having duplicate containers or wonky, unclear stuff going on is well worth it.

Comment: @Adam: The fact you use `runat="server"` essentially adds the overhead of it being a .NET control and a `Panel` renders to `div` so my _reasoning_ would be to keep the project .NETified.

Comment: It's true that it's not as good as a plain old HTML element, but the overhead incurred from a HTMLControl is less than a normal .NET control.  There's events that don't get fired, properties that don't exist, etc.  It's a more lightweight control.  Plus, regardless of the overhead, I value control over my markup and don't trust Microsoft to make it not be trash.  All of _that_ being said, the case is valid that if he does this nowhere else and it'd create a weird inconsistency, using it might not be worth the benefits.

Comment: See this link for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsyt68f1.aspx  You'll note that they explicitly call out that .NET Controls have a bunch more features (which means overhead) and state that you lose a one-to-one mapping between control and rendered HTML tags.

Comment: @Adam Fair enough, I'll take your word on the link content, it's not that I'm unaware, just not to concerned with the negligible overhead in this very instance. So long as the OP can get a working solution.

Comment: I'll agree to that!  It's negligible in the end.  My case is more for the "control" side of things.

Answer (score 0):

OK - Javascript and jQuery won't work directly with an ASP.NET `PlaceHolder` control. This is because such a control is server-side only, and doesn't get rendered directly to the client but rather only what is either within it, or overriding it, so:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="myPlaceHolder">
    ???????????
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Is output as:

```
"



   ???????????


"
```

Spaces, and all. Therefore, the identifier you use in jQuery (`$'#placeHolder'`) has no standing here as it doesn't identify anything. So, the short answer goes like this:

You can't determine directly, using jQuery, whether or not the `PlaceHolder`.

You might want to take some level of interest in @Tom's answer and he seems to have provided a script / client-side solution, albeit venturing away from the languages starting with `j`. ;)

Comment: Yea I was starting to get that feeling. Is there a work around to this? Say I had a div in the placeholder <div id = "foo"> is there a way I could attempt to get that id and determine what is visible that way ( if($('#foo').visible) or something like that)? Or would I run into issues when that placeholder is not visible because the div does not exist?

Comment: I'm no expert with jQuery so it would take a little experimenting on my behalf in order to definitively answer your comments, and also at work right now - however, I don't mind doing so at all, and if you don't have an answer by the time I get a chance to do so, then I certainly will and let you know. But, I would say look into how to determine if the `($'#id')` construct returns a known instance, or not.

Comment: You can definitely do that (have a nested DIV) and indeed someone else suggested that, but you _might_ want to check out my answer below and avoid all of this....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one?

`if (jQuery('#showClosest').is(':visible')) {`

Comment: This wont work as the Placeholder control doesn't render to any HTML

Comment: ha, ok, sorry for this. So you just have to test the length of the jQuery selector as @daniellmb stated

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Tom Gullen's harshly-downvoted answer, if your requirement is to determine which of the placeholders on the page is visible and there will only be one visible at a time, then you can use a property to return the ID of the visible one:

```
public string VisiblePlaceHolderID
{
    get
    {
        return this.Controls.OfType<PlaceHolder>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Visible == true).ClientID;
    }
}
```

This will return the ID of the first placeholder on the page that has `Visible="true"`, which you can then use directly in your JavaScript, something like this:

```
alert("<%= this.VisiblePlaceHolderID %>");
```